# como mostrar datos guardados en Firebase database con android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase

Amigos estoy haciendo un proyecto en Firebase database con android y requiero consultar y obtener los ultimos tres valores guardados con el nombre de "dosis"
esta es la estructura en Firebase
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi clase usuario.java

```
public class usuario {
private String email;
private  String dosis;
private String id;
private int dia;
private int mes;
private int año;

public usuario(String email, String dosis, String id, int dia, int mes, int año) {
    this.email = email;
    this.dosis = dosis;
    this.id = id;
    this.dia = dia;
    this.mes = mes;
    this.año = año;
}
public usuario() {

}

public int getDia() {
    return dia;
}

public void setDia(int dia) {
```

............

Asi es como estoy obteniendo el valor en un activity y dentro de un boton tengo

```
my.orderByChild("usuario").limitToLast(3).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        usuario us =dataSnapshot.getValue(usuario.class);
                    textViewcalculo.setText(us.getDosis());

                }
```

pero en el debug me sale esto al presionar el boton en el cual estoy realizando el llamado. 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien que me puede indicar si es la manera correcta o si existe otra y cual seria ?
Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proba con esto

```
    my.child("usuario").orderByKey().limitToLast(3).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                               usuario us =snapshot.getValue(usuario.class);
                            textViewcalculo.setText(us.getDosis());
                            Log.e("Datos: " , "" + us.getDosis());
                                    }


                        }
```

recorda que al ser un textview va a setear solo el ultimo valor por el for, pero podes poner un log y fijarte si te trae los 3

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte Amigo, pero no me funciono

Comment: Me sale lo mismo en debug ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
                ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1

Comment: que te devuelve?

Comment: dodne apunta la referencia  my ?

Comment: No muestra nada en el TextView

Comment: DatabaseReference my = database.getReference();

Comment: database es getInstance() no ?

Comment: FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

Comment: proba con el codigo editado

Comment: Esta asi el orden 
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference my = database.getReference();

Comment: recorda que al ser un textview va a setear solo el ultimo valor por el for, pero podes poner un log y fijarte si te trae los 3

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84073/discussion-between-gaston-saillen-and-julian).

Comment: Mil gracias Amigo, buena noche